# Jenkins copy files error after docker npm build

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a script similar to this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            label 'dev' 
            image 'node:12-alpine' 
            args '-p 3000:3000' 
        }
    }
    environment {
        HOME = '.'
    }    
    stages {
        stage('clone repo') {
            steps {
                git(
                    url: '...',
                    credentialsId: '...',
                    branch: 'master'
                )
            }
        }
        stage('install dependency packages') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('build prod ready enviroment') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            agent { node { label 'dev' } }
            steps {
                sh "cp -rf ./build/* /opt/www_folder/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now everything works fine except deploy stage which just hangs up building process. If I run only last stage (deploy) separately without other stages it works fine. I think there is a conflict with a docker agent but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the best answer but I managed to fix my problem with this script:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
        HOME = '.'
    }    
    stages {
        stage('clone repo') {
            agent { node { label 'dev' } }
            steps {
                git(
                    url: '...',
                    credentialsId: '...',
                    branch: 'master'
                )
            }
        }
        stage('install and build') { 
            agent {
                docker {
                    label 'dev' 
                    image 'node:12-alpine' 
                    args '-p 3000:3000' 
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            agent { node { label 'dev' } }
            steps {
                sh "rm -rf /opt/www_folder/*"
                sh "cp -rf ./build/* /opt/www_folder/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```